# You must publish at least one action to your Timeline using this action type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Hi I just define my custom action on facebook using open graph. After creating the action when i want to submit the action it creates the error.

```
 Publish Actions
You must publish at least one action to your Timeline using this action type. Review the documentation.
```

And give me the link to this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/) where I can see only the urls of graph api. If I am doing some thing wrong?

Can any body please tell me how to get rid off this error? How can I publish action on my timeline so that I can submit my action for approval?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test the action first on your site/app. Facebook will check your timeline and then only Facebook approves it.

**[EDIT]**

Submitting is for allowing public to use those. But admin/developers can use publish actions on Facebook. To publish these actions on timeline,  you can use [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1274834235) or using php or js or etc

**[EDIT]**

> Actions are defined through the App Dashboard. Once an application has
>   defined the types of actions that it publishes, the application can
>   invoke the Graph API to publish action instances to Open Graph -- this
>   connects the current user with an appropriate object instance via the
>   action.

`POST /me/{namespace}:{action-type-name}`

> The following call establishes
>   a Cook connection between the current user and a Pumpkin Pie (an
>   instance of the Recipe object type):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/recipebox:cook?  
 recipe=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

> Here is another example using the Javascript SDK:

```
 FB.api('/me/recipebox:cook', 'post',    { recipe :
 'http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' });
```

FYI: [Post Actions on Timeline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/)

Comment: thanks dude. How can I test this? Can you please more elaborate it?

Comment: But I am not getting these instructions. When I click on submit link it generates the error as the title of my question

Comment: I had given more info for you to explain better. Ignore it for now

Comment: I think I am dumb today:-(  what to give on grapi api explorer? it is just grabbing the information of the user? what is its link with pulishing my action on my timeline?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12293/discussion-between-venu-and-awais-qarni)

Comment: i got some doubt, 'http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' what is this url actually? dose it points to where my app is hosted? like url to appspot.com or dose facebook generated code give correct url, do i have to change the generated url?

Comment: Can I make a Private post to get it verified? Or I need to make a Public Post?

Comment: Geeze all these words make no sense to me

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) page, select your application in the 'Application' drop-down.

Set Method to 'POST and in the url enter in the format https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_ID/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE:YOUR_APP_ACTION

Then click 'Add Field' and in name enter your action type object's name and in value enter the url of an object on your site for example. Also make sure you have included the OpenGraph Meta Tags on each object page with the crucial og:type tag set to YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION_OBJECT. An example on mine is

Comment: Your submission will still be rejected when the review team see that your app doesn't have any working publish functionality